# Re-Running A Code Block Based On a Condition

Tags: c#

I'm working on a basic console program as can be seen below. I'm rather annoyed that the latter piece of code just won't work. What is the best way to check the user's inputted age and re-run the code from Console.WriteLine("Okay. Now please enter your age."); to the if statement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Thank you for participating in this survey. Please take a moment to fill out the required information.");
           Console.WriteLine("Please Type Your Name");

            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Okay. Now please enter your age.");

            string age = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Your information has been submitted.");

            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name + "\n" + "Age: " + age);

            Console.ReadLine();

            int newAge = Int32.Parse(age);

            if (newAge => 18) 
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to already know how to convert string to an int. Please fix your title so that it correctly reflects what you _actually_ are asking for help with. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the TryParse, which does the error testing for you, and returns the parsed value as an out parameter. As TryParse returns a bool value, you can easily check if the conversion worked.

```
string age = null;
int ageValue = 0;
bool succeeded = false;

while (!succeeded)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Okay, now input your age:");
    age = Console.ReadLine();
    succeeded = int.TryParse(age, out ageValue);
}
```

you could also invert it to do... while

```
string age = null;
int ageValue = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Okay, now input your age:");
    age = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(age, out ageValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
 int newAge = Int32.Parse(age);
```

with this

```
 int newAge = Convert.ToInt32(age);
```

.
And If you want to code better use try-catch

```
try
{
int newAge = Convert.ToInt32(age);
}
catch(FormatException)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the problem of my if statement giving an error http://prntscr.com/54gmwf

Comment: You should use `>=` and not `=>`